# Use Dial in GoLang with specific local address

Tags: go

I need to be able selecting from which IP address my HTTP request should be sent. In my code right now, for DNS caching i'm using the following according to [this](https://github.com/rs/dnscache):

```
defaultTransport.DialContext = func(ctx context.Context, network string, addr string) (conn net.Conn, err error) {
    separator := strings.LastIndex(addr, ":")
    ips, err := r.LookupHost(ctx, addr[:separator])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for _, ip := range ips {
        conn, err = net.Dial(network, ip+addr[separator:])
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
    }
    return
}
```

In order to specify the local address, the only way i found is by using the following:

```
defaultTransport.DialContext = (&net.Dialer{
    LocalAddr: localAddr,
}).DialContext
```

How can i achieve combining the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the local address dialer that you want to use, and delegate the actual calls to it?

```
localAddrDialier := &net.Dialer{
    LocalAddr: localAddr,
}

// trimmed...

defaultTransport.DialContext = func(ctx context.Context, network string, addr string) (conn net.Conn, err error) {
    separator := strings.LastIndex(addr, ":")
    ips, err := r.LookupHost(ctx, addr[:separator])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for _, ip := range ips {
        // use the localAddrDialer here for the _actual_ request?
        conn, err = localAddrDialer.DialContext(ctx, network, ip+addr[separator:])
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Or vice-versa, according to which if the `net.Dialer`'s you want to make the *actual* call

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own Dialer which will use your specific Local Address using net package of Golang like this:

```
dialer = &net.Dialer{
    LocalAddr: &net.TCPAddr{
        IP:   net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1"),
        Port: 0,
    },
}
conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:2525")
```

You can also specify your specific Port.But using Port 0 means it will use any dynamic port value to make connection to another Server.